# Android Receiving Broadcast NFC ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, configuration, nfc, broadcast

i am creating an NFC enabled app and want to display a warning if NFC is disabled.

One possibility to do this seems to be to check if NFC is enabled in onResume, however if NFC is enabled from quicksettings onResume is never called.

To update the message if the user enables NFC, I want to listen to the Broadcast "android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED", so let's create a intentFilter, with the same code as used in the [Android Settings app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/master/src/com/android/settings/nfc/NfcEnabler.java):

```
mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED);
```

Which gives me the message "ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED cannot be resolved or is not a field". However, if i open the sources to NfcAdapter, the field is definitely there:

```
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String ACTION_ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED =
        "android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED";
```

I don't get this at all... How am I supposed to react to changes in NFC configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to pass the String constant itself?

Comment: I did not, it works perfectly and I now feel kind of stupid...
But I still don't know why the Constant seems to be undefined.

Comment: Seems like it could not make up to the SDK :)